# Distinct SQL Queries returning multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

In my SQL Server I have these two tables:

```
a
id  |  name  |   code   | lastpur  | lastprc
```

and

```
b
num  |  code |  onHand  | isComm   |  avgPrc
```

And I want to do a query that prints all of these fields (there are more on the tables, but they don't need to be accessed for now.

Both tables are connected by the field `code`. My problem is that there is only 1 entry on `a` whereas in `b` I have 1 or several. So I tried this query:

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  a.id, 
                            a.name, 
                            a.lastpur, 
                            a.lastprc, 
                            b.onHand, 
                            b.iscomm, 
                            b.avgPrc, 
                            (b.onHand - b.isComm) AS available 
            FROM a, b
                WHERE a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode AND
                      a.id LIKE '%".php_variable1."%'
                      a.name LIKE '%".php_variable2."%'
```

The problem is that this query returns the number of all the entries in table `b`. For example if there is 2 with code 123, it will return 2 rows, if therer is 4 it returns 4. I need just 1. If it finds a match, then return.

Afterwards I heard about nested statements so I wrote:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT    onHand, 
                    iscomm, 
                    avgPrc, 
                    (onHand - isComm) AS available
              FROM 
              (
                   SELECT id, 
                          name,
                          code,
                          lastpur,
                          lastprc
                       FROM a
                       WHERE id LIKE '"%.php_variable1.%"' AND
                             name LIKE '%".php_variable2."%'
              ) alias, b
          WHERE alias.code = b.code
```

However I'm not very familiar with nested and I got some, not very helpfull errors (I am using PDO and it just read 'error in syntax near') that I could not debug. So can anyone tell me where I went wrong and help me get this out of the way?

Comment: you are using MariaDb or mySql or SQL Server or all 3 Products?

Comment: I'm using all 3. So I got this confused. This part is just SQL Server. I'm really lost right now.

Comment: So, the usual behavior in a situation like this is that you *want* all of the options from `b` -- Unless you have another condition for "which row from b should be used" you're just making an arbitrary choice of which row to take.  If you want that arbitrary choice, a `GROUP BY a.id` (to squash multiple copies of `a.id`) will do what you want, rather than the `DISTINCT` (you don't need that).  `DISTINCT` is for removing duplicates... which you don't have since the `b`'s make the results different.

Comment: I've tried the `GROUP BY` with code and id and I got the aggregate error. But I think it is the way to go, need to explore this a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.*, (b.onHand - b.isComm) AS available 
          FROM a
          CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 b.*
            FROM b
            WHERE a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
          ) b
          WHERE a.id LIKE '%".php_variable1."%'
            AND a.name LIKE '%".php_variable2."%' "
```

Comment: I can't do the `a.*` or `b.*` on this case, but I'll try this code. Thanks.

Comment: you are my hero. Spot on! Thanks so much!